Domestic robot sacrifices itself rather than harm family
This is a novella or short story, likely in an anthology, written before 1995.
A family had an android servant. It accepted English instructions but sometimes misunderstood them or took them too literally. Such mistakes often led to behaviour that amused the youngest child, such as juggling household objects. It was explained that it had no real intelligence or creativity, so these events must have been coincidences.
A subversive group tried to take over the country by remotely controlling all household robots and using them to take the owners hostage. The family was lined up against a wall and warned not to move.
After some time the robot started moving oddly, eventually destroying itself. Some time later, a news announcement explained that the authorities had regained control and deactivated all the robots, damaging some in the process.
While they'd been against the wall, only one family member had a view of a clock. (S)he realised that the robot destroyed itself before the authorities could have sent the signal to deactivate it, meaning that it had made the decision on its own to protect the family - so it had been more intelligent and aware than was believed possible.
